# Workspace settings vs project specific settings

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, configuration

I am thinking about the best way to keep the eclipse configuration for several developers consistent. By configuration I mean uniform

- compiler settings
- checkstyle configuration
- code formatter
- save actions
- file encoding

Thats are all things which the developers have to configure themselves in the eclipse preferences by working off a checklist. What do you think of configure everything project-specific for each project so the configuration can be checked in into version control? Then the developer just has to checkout/update the sources and all configuration is done already. Are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure these at the project level and keep them in the code repository, but I've had problems with developers checking in their customized configurations before.

You might want to consider Robert Konigsberg's [Eclipse Workspace Mechanic](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-workspace-mechanic-for.html) for managing Eclipse configurations.

Comment: What where the problems you had? The plan is that only one person is allowed to modify the configuration in the version control... ;)

Comment: I've never had a repo administrator willing to manage permissions at the file level. Every developer could commit any file in the repo. If your setup is different, good for you. I'd still suggest looking at Eclipse Workspace Mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

There will be problem when some of the path are hard coded i.e. absolute instead of relative path.